# how to write a windows kernel mode debugger?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, kernel-mode

I want to write a kernel mode debugger for windows like [windbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx). Is there any SDK or demo can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean you want to use the underlying engine and write a variation then you can explore AttachKernel DebugEng Function check [DbgEng-based-Kernel-Debugger-woodmann.com](http://www.woodmann.com/forum/entry.php?250-DbgEng-based-Kernel-Debugger) if you want some pointers

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thanks a lot!